# Why the count of items in a store which is not autoLoad is 0?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1.

I have a Store like this:

```
var predictTargetStore = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    autoLoad : false,
    fields: ['label','value'],
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'predictTargetList'
        }
    }
});
```

I will do predictTargetStore.load({url : 'getPredictTargetList.action'}) some time later.after I have done this,the combobox which used predictTargetStore will have choices.
but when I try to get one item from the store,I failed.I do like this:

```
predictTargetStore.load({
    url : 'getPredictTargetList.action'
});
var value = predictTargetStore.getAt(0).get('value');
```

I find predictTargetStore.getAt(0) is null and predictTargetStore.getCount() is 0.
so how can I get one item of the store?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried, Following will do the trick:

```
user.load({
    scope: this,

    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    user.each(function(record) {
        console.log(record.get('name'));
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the server response :

```
predictTargetStore.load({
    url : 'getPredictTargetList.action',
    callback: function () {
        var value = predictTargetStore.getAt(0).get('value');
    }
});
```

Details about the `callback` function [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-cfg-callback).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar issue with following codes:
`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.EOrder.Model.TestRequest', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [{
            name : 'testId',
            type : 'int'
        }, {
            name : 'testCode'
        }, {
            name : 'testName'
        }, {
            name : 'price',
            type : 'float'
        }
    ]
});

var testStagingStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model : 'MyApp.model.EOrder.Model.TestRequest',
        storeId : 'StagingTestRequest',
        autoLoad : false,
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'LOINC.json',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'TestRequest'
            }
        },
        listeners : {
            load : function () {
                loadedCount = this.data.getCount();
                console.log('json file loaded. processed records:' + loadedCount);
            }
        }
    });

testStagingStore.load();

console.log(testStagingStore.data.items);    // in chrome "network" console, I know my json file was loaded successfully. But here I get nothing!
```

`

Not sure whether the data property was populated properly or not.

I believe you have the same problem because getAt will retrieve records from data property .

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to mention the `url` inside the proxy or you need to use the `setProxy()` method on the store to set the URL. With out doing this, the values might not get returned. Check the sencha docs for further information.

Comment: -1, load is asynchronous, the load processing needs to happen in a callback.